# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the addition of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I start with matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$

and I express it as a sum

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} w & x \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}(a/w-1)w & (b/x-1)x \\ (c/y-1)y & (d/z-1)z \end{bmatrix}$$

I'll now call the first and second matrix on the RHS $B$ and $C$, respectively. For clarity,

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} w & x \\ y & z \end{bmatrix}$$

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}(a/w-1)w & (b/x-1)x \\ (c/y-1)y & (d/z-1)z \end{bmatrix}$$

My question is on the resulting eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Would the original eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ be preserved in the sum of $B$ and $C$? In other words, would

$$\mbox{eig} (A) = \mbox{eig} (B) + \mbox{eig} (C)$$

since $A=B+C$ in the example above?

Also, does matrix $C$ have a special name? It looks like a "relative" matrix?

I should also note, there is nothing special about the matrix other than it is square.

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ commute, at best one can say 'eig($A$)$\subseteq$eig($B$)+eig($C$)'.

Comment: @M.Vinay You are correct. I will edit that to prevent any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments following the answer given by @Erica, I decided to post a solution which I feel is more correct. I asked @Erica to make the changes, but she never took the opportunity to. I copied the following statement from @M. Vinay in the discussion comments following the answer of @Erica. I feel this is the correct answer and the example from @Erica supports it if you change the eigenvalue and eigenvector labels for $C$.

@M. Vinay states:

> If B and C have a common eigenvector, then A=B+C also has the same
>   eigenvector and a corresponding eigenvalue that is the sum of the
>   corresponding eigenvalues of B and C. For example, let v be an
>   eigenvector of B corresponding to eigenvalue λ, and also of C
>   corresponding to eigenvalue μ. Then Av=(B+C)v=Bv+Cv=λv+μv=(λ+μ)v. That
>   is, v is an eigenvector of A, with eigenvalue λ+μ.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have a rather dull matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
2&1
\end{bmatrix}\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&1 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad C=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1=3, \lambda_2=-1$ with eigenvectors $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}, v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues of $B$ are $\lambda_1=2,\lambda_2=0$ with eigenvectors $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}, v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues of $C$ are $\lambda_1=-1,\lambda_2=1$ with eigenvectors $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}, v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

While it seems that $v_1+v_2$ are equal for all three matrices, there is no similar conclusion about the relationships among the eigenvectors as you have described.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm able to follow your example, but if the matrix `A` is given by block elements `a,b,c,d`, where none of them are equal, does that make a difference in your example?

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, your example above seems to show that `eig(A)=eig(B)+eig(C)`  holds? I obviously don't want to draw any generic conclusions, but if it is true under certain conditions, then I can at least check if it holds for my specific application.

Comment: OP, sorry for not being clear. It seems that the example shows that eig(A)$\neq$eig(B)+eig(C) as you can see from the eigenvectors. Thus, since we have a counterexample, we are done.

Comment: I'm obviously not an expert in eigen problems, but is seems that all vectors are the same and the eigenvalues of B and C add up to A? Is there no significance to that?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack That's right, Jack. If $B$ and $C$ have a common eigenvector, then $A = B + C$ also has the same eigenvector and a corresponding eigenvalue that is the sum of the corresponding eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$. For example, let $v$ be an eigenvector of $B$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$, and also of $C$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\mu$. Then $Av = (B + C)v = Bv + Cv = \lambda v + \mu v = (\lambda + \mu)v$. That is, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda + \mu$.

Comment: @M.Vinay So Erica's example does show that A = B + C? I just want to be clear. Also, would you mind making your comment above an answer? I think it's very informative.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack It shows that if $A = B + C$ and $B$ and $C$ have the same respective eigenvectors, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are the sums of corresponding eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$. I'm not sure why Erica claims the opposite — maybe because with the labeling shown in the answer, it is not true that $\lambda_i(A) = \lambda_i(B) + \lambda_i(C)$. But that is only because of "incorrect" labeling.

Comment: @M.Vinay I assumed the same thing, "maybe because with the labeling shown in the answer, it is not true that...". Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack My mistake. I misread your question and thought that you were suggesting the eigenvector of $A$ is the sum of the eigenvectors of $B$ and $C$. In other words, yes, the eigenvalues are preserved as shown by M.Vinay

Comment: @Erica I thought that might be the cause of confusion. I will change that wording to prevent confusion. It sounds like M.Vinay is deferring to you for presenting the correct answer? About 5 comments up, M.Vinay gives a good mathematical explanation. Would you mind integrating that into your answer and making the necessary edits so that I can accept your answer. Also, do you have any comments about the idea of a "relative" matrix? Is that something that is well known or of any significance? (These last two questions, I'm just curious). Thanks for your help and time Erica.